# What signal is emitted when pressing CTRL+D in node:readline?

Tags: node.js, readline, ctrl

I've been trying to intercept `CTRL+D` so I can use it to represent 'document' for a CLI I am building. I have been unsuccessful identifying how to intercept it when using readline with keypress.

Is there a specific signal event I can listen for and override the default `readline` behavior to exit the application when CTRL+D is pressed?

It's also notable that `CTRL+D` does not exit the application if other keys have been pressed. But this is untenable as a solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
import readline from'node:readline'

const stdin = process.stdin
stdin.setEncoding('utf8')
const stdout = process.stdout
stdout.setEncoding('utf8')

const rl = readline.createInterface( stdin, stdout )

readline.emitKeypressEvents(stdin)
stdin.setRawMode(true)

rl.on('line', line => {
  console.log(line)
})

stdin.on('keypress', async (str, key) => {  
  if(key.name === 'd' && key.ctrl === true){
    console.log('CTRL-D')
  }
})

process.on('SIGINT', ()=>{
  console.log('CTRL+D??')
})
```

Comment: Perhaps not an answer to your question directly, but since `CTRL+d` is the signal that the node repl uses to exit the repl itself, I wouldn't be surprised if it is handled specially and perhaps doesn't even send a signal.

Comment: I saw something to that effect in my research.. Perhaps I can send some phantom rl.writes that I don't display to achieve my goal..

Comment: I would choose a different key combo for fear that you will confuse your users who might be used to the node repl and somehow render you repl "unexitable".

Comment: I wanted to use `CTRL+M` to represent 'multiline' but for whatever reason, my terminal thinks that is `return`. I've been using `CTRL-W`, but it's just not intuitive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> is not a regular operating system signal like SIGINT.

It is used on stdin as "end-of-transmission" information by readline and many others to close stdin. Here is a snippet of the [node readline source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9512da07a4eb9a8c5fb1f232524c7df7627f676e/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L1135-L1142)<sup>1</sup> handling it:

```
        case 'd': // delete right or EOF
          if (this.cursor === 0 && this.line.length === 0) {
            // This readline instance is finished
            this.close();
          } else if (this.cursor < this.line.length) {
            this[kDeleteRight]();
          }
          break;
```

I can't see a way of changing this behaviour in readline without overiding readlines `_ttyWrite` function or some type of interception before readline handles stdin.

1 - MIT Licensed. Copyright Node.js contributors

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to send some 'phantom' keys with `rl.write()`...